# Google Codejam Problem: Blindfolded Bullseye

Tags: geometry

The question arises from this [CodeJam](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/000000000019fef2/00000000002d5b63) problem, "Blindfolded Bullseye".

> Given a square of side length $ 2 \cdot10^9 $  and a circle with radius between $\frac{10^9}{2}$ and $10^9$. Given the circle completely lies within the given square, what is the minimum number of points we need to place in this square such that at least one point always lies on/in the circle?

My Attempt:

[image]

Where each dot is $\frac{10^9}{2}$ units apart and I am not able to find any counterexamples for this.
Any hints would be helpful thanks.

Comment: I believe four points will suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi there the first thing I did was spilt the square into 4 even parts where each of these mini-squares are $\frac{10^9}{2}$ in length, which is the minimum radius of the circle. These squares present the furthest part of which a circle can be shoved in, through this every circle conceived can have a point in/on it.

[image]

Hope this helped

Edit: Thanks for picking that up Parcly Taxel, well thats a simple fix we move one of the points to be on the circumference so it is the closest it can be to the origin.

[image]

Comment: Yes. What if a circle of diameter one billion is placed in the exact centre of the square?

Comment: Thanks for picking that up, well thats a simple fix we move one of the points to be on the circumference so it is the closest it can be to the origin.